# Two shapely methods to test if a point is within a polygon are failing

Tags: python, shapely, point-in-polygon

I am iterating through the polygons in a Fiona collection and am not finding my point is within any of the polygons.  I am using the shapefile from [here](https://data-ltsb.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/048f8d318c044f51b7f82a38cc00a956_0/explore).  Can you see the problem?

[How can I gracefully end the search should a match not be found?]

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fiona
import shapely

with fiona.open("WI_Municipal_Wards_(July_2022).shp") as fiona_collection:

    #
    # The point of interest
    #
    point = shapely.geometry.Point(-92.7348222, 44.9644745) # longitude, latitude

    #
    # Access the first record of the fiona collection
    #
    shapefile_record = fiona_collection.next()

    #
    # Iterate through the fiona collection
    #
    while not (shapefile_record is None):

        #
        # Print the label of the current record (for debugging)
        #
        print(shapefile_record['properties']['LABEL'])

        #
        # Use Shapely to create the polygon
        #
        shape = shapely.geometry.shape( shapefile_record['geometry'] )

        #
        # Is the point within the polygon?
        #

        # Alternative: if point.within(shape)
        # if point.within(shape):

        if shape.contains(point):
            print("Shape found for point.")
            print(shapefile_record['properties']['LABEL'])
            break

        #
        # Get the next polygon
        #
        shapefile_record = fiona_collection.next()
```

Comment: are you sure that your data is storing polygons as lat/lon and not lon/lat?

Comment: I did `ogrinfo -al` on your SHP files and it starts `POLYGON ((-9997923.886906804516912 5459189.998421849682927,-9997838.170984933152795 5459188.76125318929553,-9997810.229673294350505 [...]`, suggesting your data may not be in longitude/latitude format, though I'm not sure if Fiona automatically reprojects or not. From the ogrinfo headers, it appears to be EPSG 9001: https://epsg.io/9001 Note that the GeoJSON version has latitudes and longitudes and I was too lazy to check the other file types

Comment: @BarryCarter, thank you for cluing me in on the SHP file containing polygons that weren't longitudes/latitudes.  The GeoJSON file worked great!

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you for asking about lat/lon versus lon/lat.  The problem was the content of the SHP file.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was the content of the SHP file, switching to geojson was the fix.

The graceful end to the search was fixed by using "for shapefile_record in fiona_collection" for iterating.

Here's the result:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.11

import fiona
import shapely

with fiona.open("WI_Municipal_Wards_(July_2022).geojson") as fiona_collection:

    #
    # The point of interest
    #
    point = shapely.geometry.Point(-92.7348222, 44.9644745) # longitude, latitude

    #
    # Iterate through the fiona collection
    #
    for shapefile_record in fiona_collection:

        #
        # Print the label of the current record (for debugging)
        #
        # print(shapefile_record['properties']['LABEL'])

        #
        # Use Shapely to create the polygon
        #
        shape = shapely.geometry.shape( shapefile_record['geometry'] )

        #
        # Is the point within the polygon?
        #
        if shape.contains(point):
            print("Shape found for point.")
            print(shapefile_record['properties']['LABEL'])
            break
```